# Pre-1996 YA fantasy - female cat burglar

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I have been trying to remember the title/find this book for over a decade. The main character is an orphan. I think she is slightly psychic? She becomes a thief but hates stealing; at one point she steals a button instead of an expensive coin when pick-pocketing. She also steals a peacock feather glove from a princess or something?

Comment: I'd say that had *God Stalk* come out in more recent times, it'd be solidly in the YA section. Jame's about 19-21 in the first book, near as I can find, but given they don't have legal adulthood until 27 and longer lives she's equivalent to a teenager. It's also in a dystopia (Rathillien is a doomed world slowly being destroyed), meeting another YA trope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like [P.C. Hodgell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P._C._Hodgell)'s [*God Stalk*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/69169.God_Stalk). It wasn't marketed as young adult though. The main character is Jame (short for Jamethiel) who's trying to find her twin brother Tori. She's a Kencyrath, not human, and has retractable claws which she tries to hide with gloves. She ends up in Tai-tastigon, dancing at tavern, and a member of the Thieves' Guild. Mayhem and destruction follows in her wake...

It's had a checkered publishing history. Two books were published initially (GS plus *Dark of the Moon*). Nine years later, the third book was published, and 12 years after that, book 4.  Baen has published the first 4 books in two omnibuses (also available as ebooks), the fifth book last year and a sixth book is being published in December. Hodgell is now retired, so she's writing much faster.

Comment: The peacock feather gloves kind of clinch it, I'd say.. Here -- this might be helpful to confirm: http://kencyr.wikia.com/wiki/Kencyr_Wiki