Fantasy book series about a girl with magical red hands
Read a three book series where the main character was a girl with red hands.  Her hands were magical.  Was a while ago now… 20 years?!  One detail I remember is it included a group that lived on the tops of buildings and used the rooftops and spires to move around.
Help!  This has been bugging me for a couple of years now - I can’t recall the titles for the life of me!!

Hi. Was the story set within the last century or in the distant past?

If someone does post a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

A partial match would be P.C. Hodgell's Kencyrath books. The books largely follow Jame, a Kencyr thief and noble, who may be an incarnation of her three-faced god's aspect of destruction. The first book, God Stalk is set in Tai-tastigon, which houses a group of criminals named as the Cloudies who live their entire lives on the roofs of the city, with Jame being named as one of their upper-class members after she defeats one of their royalty, but spares his life. Her hands sport ivory claws due to her heritage. I don't remember her actually being called red handed, but she certainly draws enough blood, and she gains a reputation through her aspect as an avatar of destruction.


If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40037/book-where-girl-can-grow-nails-and-might-be-a-thief

Considering that the 1983 Berkley cover shows her with red...something (hands or gloves)...link should be to the cover

Good catch! I'd forgot that one.
